# Get dynamic data from external host - establish mysql-connection or get data via curl?

Tags: mysql, curl

I need to integrate a sidebar-widget into a high traffic page of mine (referred to as SiteA). This widget should contain the latest articles from one of my other pages (referred to as SiteB).

On my mind i have two possible solutions.

1. cUrl-call on SiteA retrieving the content (PHP-file) from SiteB
2. On SiteA connect to the mysql-db from SiteB

Which way would you prefer? Which is better and why?

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer setting up an RSS feed for your articles on SiteA and pulling them in with an existing library, nice and tidy, and means others can get your articles via RSS too. If I had to pick I'd probably go with option 1 (I'm assuming it just returned a snippet of HTML which you can embed in your page).

Comment: Agree completely. Prefer loose bindings over well-defined APIs.

Comment: thanks for your answer. you are correct it just returns a little bit of html. As far as i see pulling RSS data in, would mean by curl or file_get_content. So i think this doesn't differ widely from the first option. The code is really simple and straightforward, also it shouldn't be integrated o other sites, therefore i think that i will stick to option 1. But is curl faster than a extern mysql-connection?

Comment: No, you should look at pulling in the RSS feed with an RSS library, http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.importing.html for example.